# UMAP does not run on Apple M1 Pro

Tags: python, spyder, apple-m1

I have been using UMAP on an Apple 2019 i7 machine perfectly fine. However, after updating my Mac to an M1 Pro model, the command

`import UMAP`

throws many errors beginning with

`Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction`

in Spyder and restarts the kernel.

After searching I believe this is linked to the change of hardware.

Does anyone know how to get umap working on Apple silicon?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by uninstalling anaconda and installing the version compatible with Apple Silicon. All the package installations from Conda, and running of code worked after this.

(The issue I had was because I had moved from an intel based machine (MacBook i9) to an arm based based machine (MacBook m1 pro) and hence did not have the right version of anaconda installed to prevent certain conflicts as I downloaded and used packages)